# MS SQL Server 2012 Trigger Syntax

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2012

I am working on HW assignment learning about triggers and am having problems with syntax on both insert and delete DML ForTriggers as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_PERSON_ForInsert
ON PERSON
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SSN  CHAR(9)
    SELECT  @SSN  = SSN FROM  inserted
    DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT  @NAME = NAME FROM inserted  
    DECLARE @USERNAME VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT  @USERNAME USERNAME FROM INSERTED
    declare @time time(7)
    select  @time = time from inserted

    insert into PERSON_DEL_LOG
    VALUES ('New person with SSN = ' +
    Cast(@SSN as NVARchar(9)) + 
    CAST(@NAME AS NVARCHAR(50)) +
    cast(@username as nvarchar(50)) +
    cast(@time as nvarchar(20))
    )
END

INSERT INTO PERSON('012675543', 'MIKE', '5467896543', 'MUSEUM', 'INTEL', 
'BLUECROSS', '987654321')

CREATE TRIGGER tr_PERSON_ForDELETE
ON PERSON
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SSN  CHAR(9)
    SELECT  @SSN  = SSN FROM  DELETED
    DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT  @NAME = NAME FROM DELETED       

    insert into PERSON_DEL_LOG
    VALUES ('New person with SSN = ' +
    Cast(@SSN as nvarchar(9)) +
    Cast(@NAME as VARCHAR(50)) + 'is added at ' + 
    cast(Getdate() as nvarchar(20))
    )
END

DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = 987654321

SELECT * FROM PERSON_DEL_LOG
```

My `PERSON_DEL_LOG` table structure:

```
SSN, NAME, USERNAME, TIME
```

I need to know where exactly is my problem/s

Comment: Yeah, so where is your problem? Do you get any errors? Do you get unexpected data? What did you expect instead?

Comment: Give your error details.

Comment: You have an error on your *`INSERT`* statement (outside of the trigger). You also have a conceptual error that you're acting as if `inserted` and `deleted` only contain one row, when in fact they may contain 0, 1 or many rows. You need to re-write your triggers to use `inserted` and `deleted` in the `FROM` clause of set-based statements.